# deleting 10 days old folder in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")
year=$(date +"%Y")
echo $year
find  /var/backup/backup-scripts -name '*$year*' -ctime +10 -exec rm {} \;
~
~
```

This script is running with no errors but not removing 10 days old folder

Please advise

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: You are matching the file names with today's date. Are they named like so? If not, try `find  /var/backup/backup-scripts -ctime +10 -ls`

Comment: the folders are created with date and other type of files and folders also exists. So I want to remove only folders that has name like date and these are more than 10 days older

Comment: @heemayl I updated my question script and finding folder name as year but still not deleting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're single quoting a variable, it can't be expanded by the shell. Try

```
find  /var/backup/backup-scripts -name "*$year*" -ctime +10 -exec rm {} \;
```

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

@shellter's answer is a more direct mapping to your methodology, but here's how I would code that:

```
find  /var/backup/backup-scripts -name "*$(date +%Y)*" -mtime +10 -type f \
  -print0 |xargs -0 rm -v
```

Some differences:

- It's a one-liner (though if you want a cron job, make a script)
- `-mtime` ("modified") replaces `-ctime` ("changed") because sometimes access is a change
- I restricted the results to files
- I passed the output to `xargs` (in a manner safe for spaced filenames) to distribute the task

`xargs` is useful because it won't be overwhelmed by too many files (you can only send so many arguments to a command line program).  It also runs slightly faster since it will run its multiple instances in parallel.  (If it doesn't run multiple instances, there won't be any speedup, but in that case it probably won't take too long either way.)

One of the main reasons to use pipes here is that you can edit the output even further.  Let's say you wanted to keep anything from January:

```
find /var/backup/backup-scripts -name "*$(date +%Y)*" -mtime +10 -type f \
  |egrep -v "$(date +%Y)-?01" |xargs -d "\n" rm -v
```

`egrep -v` will only show lines that do *not* match the given regex, so they won't be removed.

This uses `\n` as a delimiter rather than `\0` (null), which will trip over files with line breaks in their names (don't do that!), but otherwise it excludes hits like file20150101.txt and file2015-01-01.txt (note the question mark in my extended posix regex; [further explanation at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hW2wE2/1))

Comment: `# sh delete.sh
find: paths must precede expression:  
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
delete.sh: line 6: -print0: command not found
rm: missing operand
Try `rm --help' for more information.`

Comment: I wrapped the line with a backslash.  You must either end your line with that character (no trailing whitespace or comment) or you need to smash the lines together (`… -type f -print0 …`).  `find` does indeed require the path to precede the filters.  Only a few options (all listed in your comment) are allowed before the path, and in this case there shouldn't be any.  Perhaps you modified my examples?  If so, how?  The `rm` error will happen when there are no arguments (inputs to `xargs`), which happened because you fed it the output of the command `-print0` due to the line wrapping issue.